# Calling a function in the main Form from another Class in C#

Tags: c#

how I can call a function located in the Form class from another class?

this is my code.I want call `get_data(data)` in `prog` class?

thanks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    get_data(int mydata)
    {
        //code
    }

    //code
    prog var1=new prog();
    var1.start_data();
}



public class prog
{
    public void start_data()
    {
        Thread ct=new Thread(do);
        ct.start();
    }

    private void do()
    {
        int data=40;
        get_data(data);  ///?????????????this is wrog
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here is a great answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

Comment: You'd better not call Form methods on other threads than the gui thread. In this case there isn't any issue, aslong as you do not access controls in the `get_data()`

Comment: Best idea is to pass reference of main Form when you creating another class. Than use it like `myMainForm.get_data(data);`

Comment: what do you intend to do in `get_data` ? do you want to return a value? or is it `void` ?

Comment: `get_data(int mydata)` needs a return type, up to now it has the form of a private constructor, which will not even compile...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access form methods and controls from a class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217389/how-to-access-form-methods-and-controls-from-a-class-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to access the current instance of your main form, you could pass it along to the class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal void get_data(int mydata)//Change to internal or public, as default is private
    {
        //code
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prog var1 = new prog();
        var1.start_data(this);//pass along instance of your main form
    }
}

public class prog
{
    private Form1 MainForm;
    public void start_data(Form1 form)
    {
        MainForm = form;//set form
        Thread ct = new Thread(doSmt);
        ct.Start();
    }

    private void doSmt()
    {
        int data = 40;
        MainForm.get_data(data);  //use form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you can call a method from another class you need an instance of this class. One way would be to create a new instance.

But I guess you'll have an instance of this class already because it's a form an I guess you are opening this form anywhere; just use this instance.

A hint: I would not put any business logic in my form. I would put it in another class.

```
private void do()
{
    int data=40;
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.get_data(data); 
}
```

Don't forget to make the get_data method public because you can't access it in another class when it's private.

Comment: @smk since you have not described what this method is supposed to do, we cannot guess what it means : "dont work correctly". We cannot read minds

Comment: @smk are you accessing any variables from the class `Form1` in the `get_data` method? what does it exactly mean that it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The method is not static so you need to actually instantiate the Form1 class.